# How do I access the hidden "R & R" partition on a Lenovo laptop?

Tags: partition, laptop, imaging, files

I have some Lenovo laptops (T410 / X201) and want to get the .wim files from the R & R partition.

Anyone know how I can access it? It shows in the OS (i.e. has a drive letter assigned) but shows as "empty". This is also the case if I boot into a PE environment.

Many thanks in advance,

Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a real operating system :p

(i.e. boot into a Linux using a Live CD and you'll have access to those files)